# Colon separated values in database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, database

I have database results in the following format:

```
s:6:hobbit
```

the s is "string" and the value is the count of characters in the third section. What is this called? Colon separated values? Is the only way to deal with it, in PHP, through regex?

Specifically, I'm trying to get the value `hobbit`. But obviously when I access the db to get anything I get the whole value `s:6:hobbit`. Am I doomed to using regex to work with results like this?

Comment: What database are you using? what is the schema of the table?

Comment: It's called "a design mistake".  But there are plenty of lighter-weight options for processing such a regular regular expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the output from [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/serialize). (Hint: [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/unserialize)*)

Alternatively, you can `explode()` on `:` with `limit=3`. This is important as the string itself (everything from the second `:` forward) *may* contain colons.

Also, why are these values in the DB in the first place?

---

<sup>*)</sup> **EDIT** It seems that `serialize()` would have encoded the string as `s:6:"hobbit"` (quoted) so the `explode()` could prove to be the way to do this.

Comment: "why are these values in the DB in the first place?"  It is used by a number of applications. In my case it is used in ActiveCollab.

Comment: @gaoshan88 Ok, I've seen worse :)

Comment: Yep... it's serialize. I left out the quotation marks on the string but looking at the data in the database it is def. serialize(). Thanks.

Comment: @gaoshan88 Great. As for your question "What is this called?" I guess the answer is "PHP storable representations" (in the manual) or just "PHP serialized values."

Answer (score 3):

```
list($tmp, $tmp, $string) = explode(':', $dbString);
echo $string;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/z91CztFm